# In Rails 4.2 where should I keep my static assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I'm using Rails 4.2 with the AssetPipeline. In my Sass I reference images using an absolute path like this:

```
.foo {
  background-image: url(/assets/images/foo.jpg)
}
```

This is my usual workflow for referencing assets of all kinds.

So in this case the static image `./public/assets/images/foo.jpg` is referenced. This is fine in development.

In staging and production assets are precompiled and Capistrano links the `./public/assets` directory, overwriting my assets. So apparently I'm not supposed to keep static assets in `./public/assets` since that directory is being auto-generated.

The [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) on the subject says "app/assets is for assets that are owned by the application." Well, images are own by the application. But if I put them in `./app/assets` then end up all in the `./public/assets` directory without their directory structure maintained. I don't like putting the images under app anyway. This doesn't work in all environments.

The guide also says "use app/assets for files that must undergo some pre-processing before they are served." That makes sense. It seems like a contradiction of the last statement I quoted, but I'm going to heed that advice because the images don't need to be processed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you downvote without leaving a comment, you leave me no recourse for making the question more constructive. I often start by asking a question the best way I know how. Often once I have an answer I am able to better articulate the question, potentially making it more useful to others. Downvote away, by all means, but if you are going to do it, have the guts to leave a comment.

Comment: I voted you back up to zero, some people are haters :) Your question is good.

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) gem, so you get nice helpers like `asset-path` which are both environment and magic-hash-path aware.

Comment: I am using it, but I haven't been using [the helpers](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#asset-helpers). I guess I'll try that. Still don't know where to put my images.

Comment: Ok I can deal with this. Thanks.

Comment: You put them in `app/assets` with the rest of the assets.

Comment: Yea with [greplace](https://github.com/skwp/greplace.vim) I had my app switched over in about 3 minutes. Not too painful.